# SQL query to get data till current date(considering month and date) for the particular year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need an SQL query to calculate data till current date (till current month and date) particular year. I tried following query by it filters the day of previous month too,

[image]

You can see that it filters till 11 in Jan, Feb and March. But i want to calculate the whole data for Jan,Feb and till 11th in March

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one. Generally all you need is all previous months (where days don't matter) and current month with previous days.

```
where
    (Month([OrderDate]) < MONTH(GETDATE()) OR
        (Month([OrderDate]) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND DAY([OrderDate]) < DAY(GETDATE())))
    AND YEAR([ORDERDATE]) = 1997
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `<=` instead `<` like below -

```
where day(orderdate)<=day(getdate())
```

Comment: Thanks. but Both the solution returns data till end of march (31st of March). I need to calculate till the current day (11th of March).

Comment: @VinodKumar, 11th of March 2019 or only 1997?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `MONTH` and `DAY` check within the `AND` operator will works.

Could you please try the following query with the sample data:

```
DECLARE @Orders TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, OrderDate DATETIME NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @Orders (OrderDate) VALUES 
('1997-01-01 10:00:00'), ('1997-01-15 10:00:00'), ('1997-01-13 10:00:00'),
('1997-02-02 10:00:00'), ('1997-02-20 10:00:00'), ('1997-02-13 10:00:00'),
(GETDATE()), (DATEADD(DAY, +10, GETDATE()));

SELECT *
FROM @Orders 
WHERE YEAR(OrderDate) = 1997 
      AND (MONTH(ORDERDATE) <= MONTH(GETDATE()) AND DAY(ORDERDATE) < DAY(GETDATE()))
```

Output will be:

```
Id  | OrderDate
-----------------------------
1   | 1997-01-01 10:00:00.000
4   | 1997-02-02 10:00:00.000
```

Comment: Thanks.This also results in same problem. It filters the day in previous months too. The solution which i marked as answer works fine and satisfies my need.

Comment: @VinodKumar to avoid that case, removing the `=` in the `DAY(ORDERDATE) <= DAY(GETDATE())` will work. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

just convert `getdate()` to `date`

```
where cast(orderdate as date)<= cast(getdate() as date)
```

Comment: This doesn't allow to get year 1997.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
where  (Month([OrderDate]) < MONTH(GETDATE()) 
   OR (Month([OrderDate]) = MONTH(GETDATE()) 
   AND DAY([OrderDate]) < DAY(GETDATE())))
   AND YEAR([ORDERDATE]) = 1998
```